# JMenuBar not displaying right menu options

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jmenu

-I am trying to display GUI with menubar containing menus like "Open","Run","Help" but all I am able to see in GUI is menu "File"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class test11 extends JFrame {   
   public test11(String title, int width, int height) {

        //setting up frame
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new MigLayout("debug, fillx, gap unrel rel","[grow, fill][fill]","[fill][fill]"));//no idea

        //Menubar       
        JMenuBar m = new JMenuBar();
        m.setBackground(new Color(192,192,192));

        JMenu op = new JMenu("Open");
        op.add(new JMenuItem("Catalogue"));
        op.add(new JMenuItem("Read a Paper!"));
        JMenuItem find = new JMenuItem("Find...");
        find.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));  
        op.add(find);
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_E);
        exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        op.add(exit);

        JMenu run = new JMenu("Run");
        run.add(new JMenuItem("Search My System"));  
        JMenuItem synchr = new JMenuItem("Start Synchronizer", 'S');   
        synchr.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));  
        run.add(synchr);

        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");     
        JMenuItem h = new JMenuItem("Help Contents", 'H');   
        h.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));  
        help.add(h);
        help.add(new JMenuItem("Keyboard Shortcut Card"));
        help.add(new JMenuItem("About Application"));        

        m.add(op);
        m.add(run);
        m.add(help);        
        setJMenuBar(m);  

        //Toolbar
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("Draggable");
        JButton subject = new JButton("Subject");
        toolBar.add(subject);
        add(toolBar, "span, height 20:35:50, wrap");

        JPanel table = new JPanel();
        JPanel sideBar = new JPanel();
        add(table, "width 400:600:, dock center, growy");
        add(sideBar, "width 250:300:350, dock west, growy");    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new test1("ResearchSoft",1300,700).setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

-Even changed toolbar button to "Subject" but it displays "Select"

Could anyone find out why this strange behavior happening?

Comment: nothing are strange. You are doing the changes in test11 but you are creating the object of test1. Due to that you are not looking the change made.

Answer (score 2):

You have created the object of

```
 new test1("ResearchSoft",1300,700).setVisible(true);
```

but you want to create the object of

```
new test11("ResearchSoft",1300,700).setVisible(true);
```